# Ударение в фамилии Бальмонт

Tags: фонетика

Как правильно ставить ударение в фамилии Бальмонт?

Answer (score 6):

До отъезда за границу он был БАльмонт,по возвращении стал называть себя БальмОнтом,видимо, "нашёл в своей фамилии французские корни",как смеялись друзья, тогда это было модно, романтично, он же символист.Так и остался БальмОнтом.

Кстати, прадед и прапрадед его носили фамилию Баламут, а когда дед, Константин Иванович, пошёл на военную службу, он переделал её на БальмОнт - на французский манер. Отец, зная, что он шотландских кровей, произносил БАльмонт,таких фамилий в Шотландии было много, а вот его сын повторил дедовский поступок - после поездки во Францию (в 90-е годы)добавил французскую ноту, товарищи вспоминали, что он упоминал "каприз женщины", видимо, ей нравился модный акцент, намёк на французские корни.И сам он увлёкся символизмом после "революционных юношеских заблуждений".Это был его своеобразный псевдоним. Так что оба ударения правильны.

Comment: Людмила, а источник?
По этому поводу столько всего сказано, привлекали и Цветаеву, и Гиппиус - и все двенадцать апостолов.  

>Так что оба ударения правильны.
Да! Мне вообще нравится подход "и ты тоже прав".

Comment: Источник - преподавание в 11 классе средней школы. Сейчас его биография достаточно подробно дана везде.Мы лет 6 тому назад собирали материал к литературной гостиной по Серебряному веку,сами нашли этот факт в воспоминаниях А.Белого,а сейчас об  этом везде пишут. Откройте биографию.

Comment: Ну понимаете, я видимо, читал биографию до того, как её начали преподавать в 11-м классе...
Меня интересует конкретно ссылка на документальное подтверждение того, что БАльмонт стал БальмонтОм после поездки за границу.

ЗЫ Вики даёт неработающую ссылку на некую Александрову и некий портал. Это все, что удалось обнаружить из "биографии".

Comment: Такой ссылки дать не могу. Я же не научную работу писала, а готовила открытое внеклассное мероприятие на область, искала по всем имеющимся в журналах статьям, может, в "Нашем наследии", может, в "Литературе в школе", может, ещё где нашла этот факт - не помню, помню только, что писал А. Белый.Он вспоминал, что после 1905 года, после его воспеваний революции и баррикад он нелегально уехал за границу, а в 1913 году, после амнистии в честь Романовых вернулся и произносил свою фамилию БальмОнт. Кузьмин над ним смеялся."Нам БальмОнта из Парижа принесла волна престижа..."

Comment: Баррикады он возглавил в пору смут...Ах, Кузьмин, но он же БАльмонт! БАльмонт! БАльмонт! БАльмонт! БАльмонт!-Подскажи, Поэт, кто предок?..-Ба-ла-мут?... Интернета  тогда не было, а сейчас попыталась поискать - нет. Биография есть здесь:    http://chtoby-pomnili.com/page.php?id=620  И вот ещё:"Отец произносил нашу фамилию - БАльмонт, я стал произносить из-за каприза одной женщины - БальмОнт. Правильно, думаю, первое" (письмо В. В. Обольянинову от 30 июня 1937 года) (Макогоненко, Д.Г. Бальмонт К.Д.Жизнь и судьба//Бальмонт К.Избранное.-М.,1991.-с.8). 
http://kontrolnaja.ru/dir/literature/219213